# How do we write timestamp to date time conversion in laravel 5

Tags: php

How can i write timestamp to Date time conversion while fetching data from the table in laravel 5.2. Actually i know how it do in php. But need to know the format in laravel. my code is written below, Any one can help me. Thanks in Advance.

#### Select User :

Select
                                User ID
                                User Desc
                                Contact Name
                                Contact Email
                                Time Zone
                                Active
                                Last Login (GMT+05:30)

```
                        {{--{{ UserController::getIndex() }}--}}
                        @foreach($name as $nam)
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>{{ $nam->userID }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $nam->description }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $nam->contactName }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $nam->contactPhone }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $nam->timezone }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $nam->isActive }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $nam->lastLoginTime }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Comment: It could be {{ date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($nam->your_date_field)) }}?